# "Как" и запятая

Tags: пунктуация

И снова набивший оскомину вопрос о "как" и запятых.
Известно, что, если "как" употребляется в значении "в качестве", то оно запятой не отделяется. Но я не всегда могу определить, подходит ли данное предложение под это определение. Предложение такое: "Как журналист(,) я это прекрасно понимаю". По идее, тут "как журналист" имеет значение качества - "в качестве журналиста я это прекрасно понимаю". Я права, и запятая не нужна? Или все-таки ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обособляются запятыми приложения, имеющие при себе... союзы "как" (*при осложненности причинным значением*)...

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=169#pg169
(справочник Лопатина)

(по причине того, что журналист)

Как журналист, я это понимаю  (= поскольку я журналист, это доступно моему пониманию) , но, как отец семейства (поскольку я не только журналист и имею интересы поважнее), понимать отказываюсь.

(в качестве журналиста)

Как журналист (= в качестве журналиста, журналистом) я пробыл в Африке неделю, потом остался на целый отпуск.

Answer (score 3):

Оборот с союзом КАК может иметь значение сравнения или тождества.

1) Оборот со значением тождества обособляется, если является приложением со значением причины  – АНАЛОГОМ ПРИДАТОЧНОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ ПРИЧИНЫ. Оборот может находиться в начале, в середине или в конце предложения: Как истинный художник, Пушкин видел поэтическое начало в самых простых вещах.

2) Оборот со значением тождества не обособляется, если является ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВОМ в основном сообщении со значением «в качестве». Необособленный оборот обычно находится В КОНЦЕ (РЕЖЕ В НАЧАЛЕ) предложения и является, как правило, НЕРАСПРОСТРАНЁННЫМ: Как художник  Лев Толстой гениален.  Лев Толстой гениален как художник.

3) В некоторых случаях определить значение оборота определить не так просто, например:

Я пришёл сюда как честный человек, чтобы раскрыть вам глаза (значение «в качестве»).
Я, как честный человек, намерен сдержать данное мною слово (обособленное приложение со значением причины).

"Как журналист, я это прекрасно понимаю". Здесь очевидное обособление, которое определяется не только значением причины, но и сочетаемостью слов: "понимать как журналист" - трудно определить значение этого выражения. Приехать как журналист - это понятно.